# Where to save ReactJS file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm Learning ReactJS Components and here my code is... I'm not getting where to save this file or in which folder I should keep this file?

```
<body>
 <div id="anmol"></div> <script
       src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script> <script
       src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
       <script
       src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/babel">   var NavBar = React.createClass({     
       render: function() {
           return (
                <div className='navbar navbar-deafult'> 
                <div className='navbar-header'>
                    <a className='navbar-brand'>React</a>
                </div>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav nav navbar-right">
                        <li> <a href="">Home Page </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="">About Us </a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
            );  } });   var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
           render:function() {
            return(
                <div> <h1>{this.props.children} </h1></div>
            );  } });    var destination = document.querySelector("anmol"); ReactDOM.render( <div> <NavBar/> <HelloWorld>
       HelloWorld</HelloWorld</div>,destination); </script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use codesandbox.io as well!

I created the example you were working on in there with updated syntax.

https://codesandbox.io/s/n9227v5xkp

Answer (score 2):

it look's like you are learning react, I strongly advice you to use https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app which will set-up whole environment with babel webpack and everything for you, so you can start to play with React. Greeting and have fun with React.